# Is there any difference between Firebase auth.onAuthStateChanged((user)=>{}) vs onAuthStateChanged(auth,(user)=>{})?

Tags: firebase-authentication

I am using the modular Firebase JS SDK v9, and I have seen both of these function variations used with that SDK.

Is there any difference between these...

**Variation 1:**

```
auth.onAuthStateChanged((firebaseUser) => {
  // Do some stuff
});
```

**Variation 2:**

```
onAuthStateChanged(auth, (firebaseUser) => {
  // Do some stuff
});
```

I think both work the same and both return an unsubscrubibe function.

But maybe there is a small difference I don't understand.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not really. The first one is the syntax for the namespaced SDK of v8 and before, and the latter is the syntax of the modular SDK in v9 and above. Aside from syntactic changes they do exactly the same.